# Accessing XML value with PHP

Tags: php, xml

How would you access the value of 'seconds' within this XML code using PHP?

```
<entry><yt:duration seconds='339'/></entry>
```

So far I have:

$xml -> entry -> ?!?

For Serty:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

Comment: What XML library to you use to get `$xml` variable ?

Comment: Is this the line you are looking for?

Comment: You don't edit your post as answered, you mark the correct answer below with the tick mark next to it

Comment: Also increase the point counter if you are very happy with the quality of the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you are looking for is called an attribute.  If you are using php to parse your xml, then I would look at http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php, and find a comment that helps you.

Without knowing how you are parsing it though, I can't help much more

Comment: How do you get around the yt namespace though? (i think that's the first part of the question

Comment: What do you mean by the yt namespace?

Comment: well the duration tag is namespaced yt. In simplexml (which is what I assume Will is using), is it as simple as ignoring the name space, or is there a particular way to reference the tag as $xml->entry->duration ?

Comment: Interesting, I'm also curious if there is a way to check the namespace